# Serializing / Deserializing Json to different structure using gson?

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization, gson

I would like to have different object structure created from json.

For example I would like to create json with inner object but when I deserialize it should be assigned to a field.

Example json :

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "innerData": {
    "a": "foo",
    "b": "bar"
 }
}
```

I would like to deserialize it to object with two fields - `int` `id` and `String` `b`

Comment: what value are you expecting in String b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with writing custom deserializer.